# Is there a more elegant way to write this loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, coding-style

I have a loop that prints the contents of an array with a space between each element, except for after the final element, in which case only a new line is required.

However my implementation feels "crufty" to me and I'm sure there's a more elegant way to write this, hopefully using some handy javascript trick previously unknown to me.

Here is my loop:

> ```
>                 for(var k=0; k<cycle1.length; k++){
>                     process.stdout.write(cycle1[k]);
>                     if(k<cycle1.length-1){
>                         process.stdout.write(' ');
>                     }else{
>                         process.stdout.write('\n');
>                     }
>                 }
> ```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming cycle1 is an array, use [array.join](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fjoin)

```
process.stdout.write(cycle1.join(" ") + "\n");
```

It does just what you want - takes an array, and adds the separator that you pass as an argument between each element.

Answer (score 2):

you can use join method:

```
cycle1.join(' ') + '\n';
```